# How can I compile the Rust core crate for a custom target using only cargo or rustc?

Tags: rust

I'm writing code for a bare-metal x86 target and I need to cross-compile the core crate. I want a solution that only uses cargo or rustc.

I currently use `xcargo` to compile a dummy no_std crate and copy the sysroot folder to my project.

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful? There's a section on building libcore using rustc. http://www.randomhacks.net/2015/11/11/bare-metal-rust-custom-target-kernel-space/

Comment: I followed that link and success built a file called liblib.a. How can I use that library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [unstable `build-std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#build-std) feature of Cargo:

```
cargo build -Z build-std=core --target my-custom-target.json
```

The argument can be:

- `core`
- `std`
- `alloc`
- `proc_macro`

Pass no argument for all of them.

Comment: cargo build -Z build-std failed with error: ```unresolved imports `libc::c_char`, `libc::c_int`, `libc::c_void`, `libc::uintptr_t` ```

Comment: I manage to build with this command: 'cargo build -Zbuild-std=core,alloc --target mytarget.json'